# laravel 5.3 relation model using not default keys

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model, laravel-5

I'm not using the primary/foreign key naming convention. I´ve stablished the relations between the models however I'm getting this message. 
`=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {#617}`

The following is my relation: Nationality has many Kindred.

Kindred Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kindred extends Model
{
//kindreds
protected $primaryKey = "id_kindred";

protected $table = "kindreds";

protected $fillable =     ['id_kindred','nombre_kindred','gender_kindred','bd_kindred','works_kindred','company_kindred','notes_kindred','id_natio_fk','id_mar_sta_fk','id_aller_fk','id_treat_fk','id_educa_fk','id_relat_fk','id_type_kindr_fk','id_fam_gro_fk','id_natio_fk','id_mar_sta_fk','id_aller_fk','id_treat_fk','id_educa_fk','id_relat_fk','id_type_kindr_fk','id_fam_gro_fk'];

public function Nationality()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Nationality', 'id_natio_fk' );
}

public function Marital_status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Matrital_status' , 'id_mar_sta');
}
```

Nationality Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Nationality extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey ="id_natio";
protected $table = "nationalities";

protected $fillable = ['nombre_natio'];

public function kindreds()
{
    return $this->hasMany('app\Models\Kindred' , 'id_natio_fk');
}
```

And this is the code I'm executing on the tinker command line.

```
>>> $k = App\Models\Kindred::find(111111111);
=> App\Models\Kindred {#636
 id_kindred: "111111111",
 nombre_kindred: "First Last",
 gender_kindred: "3",
 bd_kindred: "0000-00-00",
 works_kindred: 1,
 company_kindred: "Company",
 notes_kindred: "",
 id_natio_fk: 1,
 id_mar_sta_fk: 1,
 id_aller_fk: 1,
 id_treat_fk: 1,
 id_educa_fk: 1,
 id_relat_fk: 1,
 id_type_kindr_fk: 1,
 id_fam_gro_fk: 1,
 created_at: "2016-10-24 04:21:07",
 updated_at: "2016-10-24 04:21:07",
 }
 >>> $k->Nationality()
  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {#617}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to override local keys by passing additional arguments to the `hasMany` and `belongsTo` method. By default it assumes `id`, in your cases are `id_kindred` and `id_nation`.

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

so, 
**Kindred Model:**

```
public function Nationality()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Nationality', 'id_natio_fk', 'id_kindred' );
}
```

**Nationality Model:**

```
public function kindreds()
{
    return $this->hasMany('app\Models\Kindred' , 'id_natio_fk','id_nation');
}
```

Comment: Hi Sanzeeb, I applied your suggestion but it wasn't working, I was getting an error message saying the id_kindred column was not present on the nationalities table. (Which is fine) so I tried this and it flawlessly worked Kindred Model: public function Nationality() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Nationality', 'id_natio_fk' , 'id_natio' ); } Nationality Model public function Kindreds() { return $this->hasMany('app\Models\Kindred' , 'id_natio_fk','id_natio'); } If you take a look I added the id_natio instead of id_kindred, any thoughts ?

Comment: @AndréDeLaOCampos well, the third argument is the parent table's local  key. i thought of `id_kindred` i'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to display a relationship. Try this

```
$k->Nationality; // without the '()'
```

It should show the nationality or null.

Comment: Thanks for checking the question, I followed @Sanzeeb suggestion and also yours,Finally after some additional fixes, it worked just fine.